# "Your upvote will not be displayed..." actual effect

Tags: discussion, upvotes

What is the actual effect of a user upvoting a post before they have sufficient rep to?

---

I recently linked a friend (who's learning programming) to a question that I thought could be interesting for him. I had submitted an accepted answer to this question (which is how I knew of the question), but didn't think much of it at the time.

He later remarked that he'd upvoted my answer, but that as he had [low rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it wouldn't be displayed (the standard message, I can't remember it exactly). *I told him that this wasn't the intended use for upvotes*, did my civic duty, but as *I don't recall getting any rep after showing him the question*, it got me thinking:

When I was starting out, I always assumed the message meant something along the lines of "upvote won't be shown, but it'll still be treated like a normal upvote". As far as I know, there are 3 effects of upvotes:

1. Visible score change on post.
2. Post's owner gets rep.
3. Post gets a higher priority for viewing (questions become "hot", answers rise to top).

---

Which of these does "upvoting a post before having gained the upvote privilege" actually perform? From this encounter it seems like it doesn't do the first two, so I'm wondering if it does the third.